# FIX Engine supporting different versions

Tags: fix-protocol

We have developed a FIX Engine to support 4.2 version.But however we got a new Liquidity Provider who resides on FIX 4.4 version.Any ideas on how to convert the FIX 4.2 message to 4.4?

Comment: Are you using a custom engine or something like QuickFIX?

Comment: Add in processing for fields in FIX 4.4 which aren't present in FIX 4.2. Else write a FIX 4.4 -> FIX 4.2 converter which lies in betwen your FIX engine and your outside interface.

Comment: @Grant Birchmeier--Its a Custom Engine..however if there is any way to do it through Quickfix...pls let me know

Comment: @DumbCoder -- Adding a converter sounds good..do we have any such open source code in quickfix or somewhere to get some insight on how to implement..any help reg this is much appreciated.

Comment: There really is no automatic way to do this.  Whatever you do, you'll need to write custom code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using quickfix you can extract and fill FIX messages using the most abstract type: quickfix.Message. Both quickfix.fix42.NewOrderSingle and quickfix.fix44.NewOrderSingle have the same supertype.

```
private void processNewOrder(quickfix.Message message) {
    String symbol = message.getString(Symbol.FIELD);
    char side = message.getChar(Side.FIELD);
    ...
}
```

You can extract and fill the common fields for FIX.4.2 and FIX.4.4. For FIX version specific fields, you can check the BEGIN_STRING field and identify the FIX protocol version.